# Refresh random "token"

Tags: php, mysql

My script read emails from file text.txt, i want to record emails and unique random code for every email in mySQL database. All works correct, but everytime i get the same "random code".

```
I get this:
example1@stack.com vsdggd
example2@stack.com vsdggd
example3@stack.com vsdggd
I want to get:
example1@stack.com bsgfdg
example2@stack.com jhngfv
example3@stack.com sdfasd
```

Code:

```
<?php
function generatePassword($length = 6){
  $chars = 'abcdefhiknrstyz';
  $numChars = strlen($chars);
  $string = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $string .= substr($chars, rand(1, $numChars) - 1, 1);
  }
  return $string;
}


include('../connect.php');
$query = 'insert into cc (email,token) values ("%s","'. generatePassword(6) .'");';

$lines = file('text.txt');//your filename
for($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++){
mysql_query(sprintf($query, mysql_real_escape_string($lines[$i]))) or die(mysql_error() . '<br><br>' . '<b>Query:</b> ' . $query);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please, correct your question! Explain what you mean for token and, above all, what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are only calling generatePassword() once, to fix your code as it is, you want:

```
<?php
function generatePassword($length = 6){
  $chars = 'abcdefhiknrstyz';
  $numChars = strlen($chars);
  $string = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $string .= substr($chars, rand(1, $numChars) - 1, 1);
  }
  return $string;
}


include('../connect.php');
$query = 'insert into cc (email,token) values ("%s","%s");';

$lines = file('text.txt');//your filename
for($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++){
    mysql_query(sprintf($query, mysql_real_escape_string($lines[$i]), generatePassword(6))) or die(mysql_error() . '<br><br>' . '<b>Query:</b> ' . $query);
}
?>
```

So that generatePassword() gets called for each row.

Also you should really be using the newer mysqli or ideally PDO as the older mysql is deprecated and has been removed from PHP7.